# Pyinstaller executable is crashing?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm attempting to use pyinstaller to make an executable for my python program.

I've already tried the following commands, `pyinstaller --debug --onefile run.py`, `pyinstaller --onefile -w run.py`.

When run with the debug option the program starts up and starts finding the necessary imports for the program. It then executes a print statement I placed at the beginning of the program. Immidately after the print statement it starts running destroy statements. Then the command window closes and the program never opens.

When run without the debug option the program loads for about ten seconds then a windows message box appears with the error 'Failed to execute script run'. This message box does not appear with the debug option disabled.

I am using tkinter for this program. Had a couple thoughts that tkinter may be the problem but no real evidence, just a hunch. Any advice is welcome, thanks.